# SwiftUI: Get sidebar isCollapsed state on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using a `NavigationView` to create a sidebar on macOS. I can toggle the sidebar using this code:

```
Button {
    NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(
    #selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
}
```

I'm now trying to display a label while the sidebar is hidden. Triggering this in the button will not work because the user can also hide the sidebar by resizing it.

There is an `isCollapsed` property on `NSSplitViewItem` and I assume this is what I might have to check for, but I have no clue how to access it with SwiftUI. Or is there another way to check for sidebar visibility?

Comment: If you need such functionality it is better to use AppKit instead of that hack, because it might stop working with next OS update.

Comment: It's a very minor feature in a large SwiftUI project and I would prefer to take the chance of it breaking later on than to rewrite everything for AppKit now. So if there is a hacky solution I'll gladly take it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to find `NSSplitViewController` (which is still used internally as engine) and subscribe to observe its first split item (which is our sidebar) `isCollapsed` state.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2.1

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
  // find split view through hierarchy
  while sview != nil, !sview!.isKind(of: NSSplitView.self) { 
    sview = sview?.superview
  }
  guard let sview = sview as? NSSplitView else { return }
  
  controller = sview.delegate as? NSSplitViewController   // delegate is our controller
  if let sideBar = controller?.splitViewItems.first {     // now observe for state
    observer = sideBar.observe(\.isCollapsed, options: [.new]) { [weak self] _, change in
      if let value = change.newValue {
        self?.sideCollapsed?.wrappedValue = value    // << here !!
      }
    }
  }
```

and usage like

```
SideViewInsideNavigationView()
  .background(SplitViewAccessor(sideCollapsed: $collapsed))   // << inject finder !!
```

Complete [findings and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Get_sidebar_isCollapsed.md)

Answer (score 4):

This has become a lot easier using the new `NavigationSplitView` in iOS 16+. For example:

```
@State private var splitViewVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $splitViewVisibility) {
        SidebarView()
    } detail: {
        DetailVew()
    }
    .onChange(of: splitViewVisibility) { newValue in
        print(newValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using private API, it works on macOS 14.1

```
extension NSWindow {
    public var isSidebarCollapsed: Bool? {
        guard let adapter = property(NSObject.self, "_sidebarTrackingAdapter") else { return nil }
        guard let splitView = adapter.property(NSSplitView.self, "splitView") else { return nil }
        guard let sidebar = adapter.property(NSView.self, "_sidebar") else { return nil }
        
        return splitView.isSubviewCollapsed(sidebar)
    }
    
}

extension NSObject {
    fileprivate func property<T: NSObject>(_ type: T.Type, _ selector: String) -> T? {
        let sel = NSSelectorFromString(selector)
        guard responds(to: sel) else { return nil }
        guard let unm = perform(sel) else { return nil }
        return unm.takeUnretainedValue() as? T
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
NSApp.windows.first?.isSidebarCollapsed
```